# Why does making async:false cause the CSS to not render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, asynchronous

This is strange and I'm trying to figure out the reason why. My AJAX call is

```
    $('.edit-config').click(function() {
        var that = this;
        var msg; 
        ipt = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
        $.ajax({ url: ajaxurl,
                 method: 'POST',
                 data: { 'action' : 'config_update', 'name' : ipt.attr('name'), 'val' : ipt.attr('value') },
                 beforeSend: function ( ) { $(that).addClass('updating').text("Updating ... "); },
                 complete: function ( ) { $(that).removeClass('updating').text("Update"); },
                 success: function ( submitted ) { 
                                if ( submitted === 'true' ) { msg = "Successfully updated configuration in database";  }
                                else { msg = "Error when trying to update database"; }
                          },
                 error: function ( ) { msg = "Unspecified internal error"; }
         });
         alert(msg);
    });
```

I want to change it so that `alert(msg);` isn't called until after `$.ajax(...)` is finished running, since that's where `msg` is set in the first place. So I add in `async: false` as a parameter and then I notice that `addClass('updating')` is adding the class but the the style associated with that class is not showing up, whereas it previously did (when `async` was `true` by default).

Comment: Short answer: don't use `async:false`.

Comment: The answer to this question is always, ***never, ever, ever, never use `async: false`***

Comment: But I actually want it to block this time lol

Comment: No, you don't, lol !

Comment: Well, if you want it to block then you need to accept that your UI will be laggy and non responsive. Good luck fixing it.

Comment: Use something like a modal dialog to block user actions until the  ajax call is done, don't lockup their interface, you will just piss them off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you are telling it to run synchronously, it's taking your only thread to work. That means it's busy waiting for the network call instead of being responsive. You can't do **anything** while a network call is running synchronously. Don't do it.

**Don't ever use `async: false`.**

Just in case that wasn't clear, `async: false` is **BAD**. In fact, some browsers don't even let you do it anymore.

If you need the `alert()` to run after the call, just put it inside of the success/error callbacks.